# Why can't I mirror some poses?

Tags: animation, rigging

For some reason I can't mirror some poses. The arms and the legs copy the mirror pose partially, and it looks totally weird when trying to mirror a whole animation. Is there a proper way to do this?

blend.file:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36642

Comment: The poses don´t have all the hierarchy of bones keyframed, and for some reason, if I keyframe every pose with -insertkeyframe menu\ whole character- the problems are gone but I end up with a lot of unnecessary keyframes.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the axis I was going to use the most I changed some bones from the default rotation order to another axis rotation order (Euler XYZ to ZYX for example), but I forgot to change the rotation mode on the other side of the rig.

After fixing the rotation mode in both sides everything works fine:

[image]